# How to separate git projects on same server

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, branch, production

I am a front-end developer and I have no much experience about setting git environment. Do not judge me even it is a dummy question.

I have created a repository on bitbucket and it's hosting on my linux server.

Let's say project name is "myproject-test" and repository is [git@bitbucket.org:myusername/myproject-test.git](http://git@bitbucket.org:username/myproject-test.git)

This repository will be used for development and testing. Here is my question: Should I create another repository for production? Because I want separate the url's of dev and prod.

This is how I access my dev project: http://serverip/myproject-test

How can I set up my prod project to access like http://serverip/myproject ?

I have another idea like using "master" branch as a prod. But in this scenario, I don't know how to separate url's for dev and prod on my server.
Any idea would be helpful

Comment: "Because I want separate the url's of dev and prod." — why this is a requirement? I'm asking because typically you'd use different *Git branches* in a single repository to maintain the development and production versions.

Comment: @kostix thanks for comment and question. I want to use http://serverip/myproject-test url for development and to see development's master branch. Also I want to use http://serverip/myproject url for production. My goal is using test repositories's master branch as a production and see project on http://serverip/myproject. But I couldn't figure it out how to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry, I might have been not clear. Let's take another stab. Do you mean URLs the different vestions of your *deployed sites* should be accessible at? If yes, this has absolutely no relation to Git repository (or repositories). What URL maps to what physical location is the task of the web server. What *data* is placed at those location is completely outside of the realm of the web server. If you want that data to be checked out from a Git repository (or repositories) just do that.

Comment: …and I'd then go for different branches in a single repository.

Comment: @kostix many thanks. Now I am getting why it has no relation to Git. It is more about deployment.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to maintain separate code bases for each environments.

You can use git branching feature to manage environments.

e.g you can keep new developments in a separate branch. Let's call it 'dev' branch and keep production code in master branch (default branch)

Following links would be helpful for further references.

https://barro.github.io/2016/02/a-succesful-git-branching-model-considered-harmful/
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: How can I see other branchs on browser? Can you give me an example for master and branch urls? Like http://ipaddress.com/myproject and http://ipaddress.com/myproject-branch

Comment: Are you using bitbuck or github as repository  git repository manager or you are running your own server?